# Hive, pass different row into a function

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables. In first table, each row represents a polygon. In second table, each row represents a point. I want to find if each point within one of the polygon. I try to use ST_Contains, ST_MultiPolygon, and ST_Point in hive. I think there is a way to feed all rows into ST_MultiPolygon, but not sure how to do that. The following is my test data.

`pid |        shape
   1 |  [2,0,3,0,3,1,2,1]
   2 |  [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]`

This is Polygon table.

`pid | x   |  y
1   | 0.5 | 0.5
2   | 2.1 | 0.5
3   | 1.5 | 0.5`

This is Point table

I want to get the result like

`pid | is_in
 1  |  true
 2  |  true
 3  |  false`

Here is the way I think to solve this problem. what I wanna do is to determine if a point is in one of the Polygon that is stored in hive. Suppose I have 2 polygons [2,0,3,0,3,1,2,1] and [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1], actually they really are [(2,0), (3,0), (3,1), (2,1)] and [(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)]. The reason that I stored in this odd way is because ST_MultiPolygon takes this kind of format as a parameter, like ST_MultiPolygon(array(2,0,3,0,3,1,2,1)). Combined ST_MultiPolygon with ST_Contains and st_point, I can get a boolean result that indicates if a point is in a MultiPolygon. ST_MultiPolygon can even takes multiple arrays, such as ST_MultiPolygon(array(2,0,3,0,3,1,2,1), array(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)). By this way, if there is a way for me to feed all Polygons into MultiPolygons, then I know if a point in one of the Polygon.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you kindly  explain clearly

Comment: Sure, I add another paragraph at the end. Hope this will make the problem a little bit clear.